# Setting Constant Service Url in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, constants

I have a service url (http://servicetest.com/api/) getting datas through the restful service.

I want to ask a question that what is the best way holding this constant?. Is it appropriate holding it in strings.xml or applicationcontroller class, or etc. Because according to my needs, I can use service url in every activity. That's why, it should be accessible from anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to create a class constants(urls or whatever you want to name it) and declare all constant variables as static there so you can access them everywhere in your app without creating an object and when you need to change is you have to change only at one place,hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

Just create a class like this:

```
public class AppConstants {

    public static final String URL = "http://servicetest.com/api/";


    /* private Constructor to avoid instanciating this class */
    private AppConstants() {}
}
```

Use it that way, e.g.:

```
MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
task.execute(AppConstants.URL);
```

Answer (score 1):

create an Interface  (i.e ProjectConstants) for declaring all your project constants like generic class manner..So you can easily access these variables everywhere in your application..

//For example

```
package com.example.myapp;


public interface ProjectConstants
{

 String SERVICE_URL = "http://servicetest.com/api/";

}
```

// you can use this URL in your application where ever you want by simply calling like this

```
 textView.setText(ProjectConstants.SERVICE_URL);
```